# Is there a way to add loading-spinner with livewire and livewire-charts?

Tags: laravel-livewire, laravel-10

I'm using livewire 3.0 and livewire-charts 3.0. I have some charts that is very slow to appear due to lots of datas. I want to add a loading-spinner that will appear instead of the chart until this one appear.
The chart generated by livewire-chart is a livewire componennt :

```html
        <div style="height:32rem">
            <livewire:livewire-column-chart
            key="{{ $columnChartModel->reactiveKey() }}"
            :column-chart-model="$columnChartModel"
            />
        </div>
```

I tried some things according to theis documentation https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/wire-loading like :

```html
        <div style="height:32rem" wire:loading>
            <div class="loader">Loading...</div>
        </div>
        <div style="height:32rem" wire:loading.remove>
            <livewire:livewire-column-chart
            key="{{ $columnChartModel->reactiveKey() }}"
            :column-chart-model="$columnChartModel"
            />
        </div>
```

or

```html
        <div style="height:32rem">
            <livewire:livewire-column-chart
            key="{{ $columnChartModel->reactiveKey() }}"
            :column-chart-model="$columnChartModel"
            />
            <p wire:loading wire:model="column-chart-model">Loading...</p>
        </div>
```

But it doesn't work.

So can I use the wire:loading livewire directive with an entire component?

Or should I try to do it with a "loading" variable and simply conditioning loader and chart display with a simple if condition?

How would you do it?